# How to capture phone number in web view android

Tags: android

I created a JSON parser to capture data and displayed in a listview. Then I open one of the url in a webview. Now I want to capture phone number in that webview to make the phone call. So how can I capture the phone number in that webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use evaluateJavascript, try:

```
String getNumber = "";
getNumber = "var np = document.getElementById('postingbody'), t;"+
        "if(np && np.innerHTML){"+
        "   t = String(np.innerHTML).match(/(\\d{3})\\-(\\d{3})\\-(\\d{4})/g);"+
        "   if(t && t.length>0){"+
        "       return t[0];"+//show first number found
        "   } else {"+
        "       return 1;"+//return integer (custom error 1)
        "   }"+
        "} else {"+
        "   return 2;"+//return integer (custom error 2)
        "}";

webView.evaluateJavascript(getNumber, new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
        Log.d("LogName", s);
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(int s) {
        if(s==1){//custom error 1
            Log.d("LogName", "phone number not found");
        } else if(s==2){//custom error 2
            Log.d("LogName", "#postingbody (DOM element) not found");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Tx.I tries this,the phone number is inside the <section> tag instead of the tel tag   Ex: <section id="postingbody">
  Have a nice honda accord ex with 147k miles on it, drives and runs great. A/C and heat works great, just had sparkplugs, oil, transmissin filter and fluid changed egr track cleaned egr cleaned but needs a new one . Has a very nice new jvc sterio with remote and it needs a new owner calls only not on net that much Bobby 817-913-1274
 </section>

Comment: @user3254031 Add your html your question (only the part that gets the phone).

Comment: @user3254031 ok, you will need regexp in javascript. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Tx. I'll try that....